# Redirect Loop issue

Tags: php, loops, redirect

I have a redirection issue and I have no idea why.. When I go to the index.php it will redirect to members.php and back and so forth. I want registered users not be able to see the index.php page so I added this piece of code above the page:

**Index.php:**

```
<? 
session_start();
$loggedin = $_SESSION['logged'];
if ($loggedin == 'TRUE') {

header ("Location: members.php");

} else {

$loggedin == 'FALSE';

}


?>
```

**Logout.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
unset($_SESSION['username']);
} 
header("location:index.php");
?>
```

**Members.php:**

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 include_once"connect.php";
 if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
header("Location: index.php");
 }else{
  $fetch_users_data = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE                           
  username='".$_SESSION['username']."'"));

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE      
 username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($query); 
 $username = $count['0'];
 }

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE      
 username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($query); 
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];

 ?>
```

Comment: Show us members.php please.

Comment: *"I want registered users **not** be able to see the index.php page"* --- Why? Registered users should be able to gain access to your home page.

Comment: You're checking two different variables in $_SESSION, index.php is looking for 'logged' and logout is looking for 'username'. Without seeing login.php, this could be the issue.

Comment: Use `$loggedin = $_SESSION['username'];` instead of `$loggedin = $_SESSION['logged'];` @user3081954

Comment: I added the member.php

Comment: You could even use the same conditional as your other pages `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ...` instead of `if ($loggedin == 'TRUE') {`

Comment: I changed it to    $loggedin = $_SESSION['logged'];
if ($loggedin) {        and it seems to work now, still pretty interested in why the previous $loggedin didn't work though

Comment: never store password in **SESSION**

Comment: It didn't work because it wasn't defined anywhere else. @user3081954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
In Logout.php:

```
<?php 

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['logged']);
} 
header("location:index.php");
?>
```